# Is it a good idea to blow hot air through drywall?

Tags: air-conditioning, hose, exhaust, air

I have a small room with no windows and I want to cool it down. A friend of mine suggested me to get a portable AC, create a hole in the wall (drywall) and put the exhaust hose through the wall. This way, the hot air would exit the room and will be diffused in between the drywalls.

Seems like a good idea ?
What could go wrong ?

Comment: I will only leave as a comment, how Do you expect to cool the room when putting hot air on the other side of the Sheetrock. When you pump air out the return has to come from some place. If you put the hot air outside then had a make up air source of cool air it could work but pumping it in the walls will actually increase the heat inside the house because of the energy used to cool the air this is why the hot air needs to be pushed outside the building envelope and fresh cooler air slowed in.

Comment: Portable ACs produce warm humid air, this could condense on the inside of your wall.

Comment: Surely your friend meant cutting a hole all the way through the wall to the outside?

Comment: @Brad He meant just cutting a hole in the sheetrock and let the air flow between the walls. 
Actually he did it in his house and told me it's working fine.

Comment: Sure @EdBeal, it is not as efficient as blowing the air outside, but I am sure it will lower the temperature. From 95 to 68, u might end up with 71.

Comment: It may cool the room but heat the structure. As the air s dehumidified I would not be concerned about many older homes use the stud bays as heat, cooling ducts but the reason that is not done any more is because of mold. It may appear to work but your power bill will increase because by not pumping the hot air outside you heat the structure. If in a multi family you may be violating fire code.

Comment: @EdBeal I see. My house was built in 2006. No that old.